# Postfix - How to process incoming emails?

Tags: postfix-mta

Does anybody know how to process incoming emails for virtual mailboxes in postfix?
I am building web application where users add new content by sending emails to application. 
Email address used for each user is custom (eg. 123456@myservice.com) and it is dynamically created as a Postfix virtual mailbox. User needs to be able to send email to his custom mailbox address (as12145ed@myservice.com) and i want to process each incoming email, parse it's contents and populate my database with data from email.
I tried using [Postfix After Queue filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) but what i really wont is to process emails once they are saved in users virtual mailbox folder.

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: I will ask it on serverfault.com. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to post it over there. The question is automatically migrated by the system as soon as 5 people vote for migration.

Comment: I consider this a programming question, albeit it's asking for a general approach.

Answer (score 13):

I can think of two possible solutions to this:

**First possibility**: You can set a custom `mailbox_command` in Postfix. For each email Postfix receives, it will call the `mailbox_command` defined in the configuration file and provide the email as plain text on `stdin`. That way, you can decide how you want to process each email. You will have to parse the headers of the email yourself though. You can take a look at the [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_command) for more of an idea on how to make this work. Additional applications like `procmail` can also act as a `mailbox_command` and help you with processing the incoming mails.

**Second possibility**: Use Dovecot to store emails. You don't need to enable the POP/IMAP modules of Dovecot. However, Dovecot comes with the fantastic `doveadm` utility which allows you to query mailboxes and read from them. With `doveadm`, you can automatically select new emails, emails from last week, read the whole email, just part of it, delete old messages, and so forth. It's a powerful utility, I use it in various scripts to purge old emails or provide `learn-as-spam` folders for users. Take a look at [the documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm) in the wiki.

Comment: `mailbox_command` is perfect for processing incoming messages, thanks. Do you know anything for outgoing ones?

Comment: how exactly can I pass message details to the ````mailbox_command```` comand / script ?