# PHP script to extract details from email and store in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to write simple php script to extract details (sender's email address, Subject name and content) from received email and store details in mongodb database.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to name your PHP (CLI) script in Postfix's configuration entry `mailbox_command`. It is suggested in this post: [Postfix - How to process incoming emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299113/postfix-how-to-process-incoming-emails) and documented here: [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_command).