# Postfix - How to process outgoing emails?

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm trying to implement a help desk application and for that I need write a PHP script to process all incoming and outgoing emails. Considering Postfix as the MTA, I've found this post which explains how to do this for incoming emails: [Postfix - How to process incoming emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299113/postfix-how-to-process-incoming-emails). It suggests using Postfix's `mailbox_command` configuration and it works like a charm. I wonder if something like that exists for outgoing emails?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "process"? 1a) see/read 1b) rewrite 1c) ... 2) Are you interested in "not only for postfix" solutions?

Comment: I've been reading Postfix documentation meanwhile and I found the `filters` as a feature closest to what I want. To clarify my needs, I want to set a PHP script for Postfix so that each time an email is going out, a copy of that email is sent to my script. Filters in Postfix do this but the problem with them is that they are a part of Postfix's delivery process. Which means if my script fails to forward the email (for any reason), the email will never be delivered. Which is something that I don't want (too much responsibility).

Comment: Sorry I forgot about your other question. I would rather stick to Postfix only.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a copy of all outgoing mail to your script, you either need:

- a milter
- a content_filter
- recipient_bcc_maps

The last option being the easiest (you bcc the mail to a mailbox on your server, where the script is able to process the mail).

BUT: If your script already generates the emails, why feed them into your script again? Postfix doesn't do much but adding a message-id header and some other, boring headers...

Answer (score -1):

You can specify content filters on incoming mails - do do so you need to modify your master.cf file in the following way:

```
...
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
  ...
  -o content_filter=yourfilter:
...
yourfilter unix - n n - - pipe
  user=[user on which the script will be executed]
  argv=php /path/to/your/script.php --sender='${sender}' --recipient='${recipient}'
```

Next you will need to write your script.php in a way that it will take the mail from properly use the parameters that has been provided (--sender=... and --recipient=...) and the mailbody will be provided from stdin.

Here is an example how can you take email from stdin (I use this one to later on use Zend\Mail\Message::fromString() to create Message object):

```
    /**
     * Retrieves raw message from standard input
     * @throws \RuntimeException if calling controller was not executed on console
     * @return string raw email message retrieved from standard input
     */
     protected function retrieveMessageFromStdin() { 
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest)
            throw new \RuntimeException('Action can be used only as console action !');

        $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
        $mail_contents = "";
        while (!feof($stdin)) {
            $line = fread($stdin, 1024);
            $mail_contents .= $line;
        }
        fclose($stdin);
        $mail_contents = preg_replace('~\R~u', "\r\n", $mail_contents);
        return $mail_contents;
    }
```

As per parameters - I use ZF2 so you should read on how to write console applications there or use different techniques, more aligned with your framework.

What is very important is that if you want the mail to be received on a mailbox - you need also to "reinject" the email back to postfix. The way I do it is following:

```
    /**
     * Reinjects message to sendmail queue
     *
     * @param array $senders            array of senders to be split into several sender addresses passed to sendmail (in most cases it is only 1 address)
     * @param array $recipients         array of recipients to be split into several recipient addresses passed to sendmail
     * @param string $sendmaiLocation   sendmailLocation string full path for sendmail (should be taken from config file)
     * @return number                   return value for sendmail
     */
     public function reinject(array $senders, array $recipients, string $sendmaiLocation) {
        foreach ($senders as $addresses)
            $senderAddress .= " " . $addresses;
        foreach ($recipients as $addresses)
            $recipientAddress .= " " . $addresses;
        $sendmail = $sendmaiLocation . " -G -i -f '" . $senderAddress . "' -- '" . $recipientAddress . "'";
        $handle = popen($sendmail, 'w');
        fwrite($handle, $this->toString());
        return pclose($handle);
    }
```

Basically you can use the above function and customize it according to your needs. Then you can execute it later using the parameters from the commandline parameters I mentioned earlier.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you please kindly explain what $this is? Thanks!

Comment: $this here referes to the Zend\Mime\Message object (as the code above is part of class that extends Zne\Mime\Message...
Basically istead of $this->toString() you can simply add a variable that contains your Mime message to be reinjected into postfix

Comment: This solely addresses incoming emails, the OP asks how  outgoing emails and your post doesn't address that **at all**

Comment: Indeed - my mistake - I have modified the response so the filter is executed for outgoing emails

Comment: The first line of this answer says "You can specify content filters on incoming mails" yet the answer itself refers to outgoing.